# Magento 2: products collection with multi-selected values of multiple attributes

Tags: magento2, attributes, collection, filter

I have numbers of custom attributes with multiple selected values in magento catalog. I need to filter products by multiple attributes having multiple selected values.

**eg:** Attribute set having a custom `color` attribute with red, black, blue and `shape` round,rectangle etc. Now I have to list products with `color` red, black and `shape` round.

What attributes filter and selector I need to use for create a listing of products with red, black, round values?

Comment: have  you got a solution for this ?

Comment: No Rohit Goel, Can you help me in this?